# How to tell which part of a webpage is associated with a specific React component

Tags: html, reactjs, components, developer-tools

I currently do not have access to React Developer Tools in Chrome. What can I do to discern where a component is on the webpage when it is not immediately clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a unique name to the component using the html name attribute, from the elements tab in the chrome develop tools you can filter on that name. If you're actually trying to see where it's at in the page, then just click on it in the elements page after filtering to it. It'll be outlined in the Chrome and you can use $0 to refer to it in the console.